# How to fix iOS Simulator [native-run] ERR_DEVICE_LOCKED: Device still locked after 1 minute on the Apple Silicon (M1)?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ios-simulator, ionic5, apple-silicon

Regardless of `--target` variable, the following commands fail:

```
ionic cordova run ios --target="iPhone-X"

ionic cordova run ios --target="iPhone 12"

ionic cordova emulate ios --debug --target="iPhone 11" -- --buildFlag="-UseModernBuildSystem=0"
```

The **error** is:

```
[native-run] ERR_DEVICE_LOCKED: Device still locked after 1 minute. Aborting.
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess native-run.
```

It's happening after I switched to Apple Silicon (M1) MacBook Pro, but I'm not 100% sure. Thanks!

Comment: 1) What happens if you simply try `ionic cordova run ios`  2) Are you able to get the emulator to start on its own?

Comment: @E.Maggini 1) it starts iPod touch... 2) yes, by default launching Simulator starts iPhone 12 Pro Max

Answer (score 5):

I'd the same issue today and it turns out that it works using the "**Target ID**" instead of "**Target Name**".

1. Check the list of available targets using `--list` option

```
ionic cordova run ios --list
```

2. Run the same command with TARGET ID.

```
ionic cordova run ios --target="...TARGET-ID-1A2B3B..."
```

---

Just to mention, I'm on INTEL-based MacBook Pro.

Comment: Even though, according to ***cordova-cli*** documentation, the `--target` option expecting the name of a device. https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-cli/

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me!

Check the list of available targets using --list option

```
ionic cordova run ios --list
```

Run the same run command with TARGET ID.

```
ionic cordova run ios --target="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
```

Answer (score 1):

For me this message occured in a different situation. The device has not yet been registered to the Apple account!

So I started it once with XCode, it registered the device automatically (for me) and then it was working.

Comment: Unregistered device was the issue for me too. Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here, I executed:

```
native-run ios --virtual --list
```

And next,

```
cordova build ios --debug --emulator && native-run ios --app platforms/ios/build/emulator/MyApp.app --virtual --forward 8100:8100 --target <TARGET ID>
```

Other alternative:

```
native-run ios --app platforms/ios/build/emulator/MyApp.app --virtual --forward 8100:8100 --target <TARGET_ID>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are three steps to solve this issue:

**Step 1a**: Make sure that you have the latest native-run by running

```
npm install -g native-run
```

**Step 1b**: Check the up to date version

```
native-run --version
```

**Step 2**: Make sure that the device is enabled as a development machine simply from your iPad/iPhone go "Privacy & Security" then set "Developer Mode" to "On"

**Step 3**: Check the list of available targets using --list option

```
ionic cordova run ios --list
```

**Step 4**: Run the same command with TARGET ID.

```
ionic cordova run ios --target="DEVICE_TARGET_ID_SHOWN_IN_STEP3"
```

**Step 5**: If the above did not work, then make sure that you have the device registered to your developer account. Open the project in Xcode, then go to "Signing & Capabilities", then register the device.